# Ethernet PoE Magnetics Pin swap

Tags: ethernet, magnetics, poe, rj45

I have the following circuit right now
[image]

Is it possible to connect PHY_TRXP0 on TD1- and PHY_TRXN0 on TD1+ and taking ETH_MX1_P from MX1- and ETH_MX1_N on MX1+ respectively? Signals on RJ45 will go as per the pin mapping?

Any suggestions are appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, but why? Also, I think it's a bad idea to directly connect the center taps together, because someone using a crossover cable could create a short. At least one set of diodes should ensure the polarity, you can also use a full rectifier if you want your device to work in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Murphy's Law got applied to someone's layout. ;)

Yes that will work as far as the details are shown. In this case, two wrongs make it right.